# Change Wagtail password in Django

Tags: django, wagtail

I have inherited a django project which uses Wagtail for CMS. When I go to (project_url)/cms/ I am asked for a username and password, which I do not have.

Is there any way to create a default user account in the settings.py file, or reset the existing account so that I can gain access to the CMS section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the [`changepassword`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#changepassword) command (`django-admin changepassword your_username`, for example) to change a password for the existing `your_username` user.

Alternatively you can create a new superuser using the [`createsuperuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#changepassword) command by running `django-admin createsuperuser`.